# Case insensitive XPath matching with custom function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xpath, mechanize

Since XPath supports custom functions I created one to make it possible to match case insensitive:

```
class XpathFunctions

  def case_insensitive_equals node_set, str_to_match
    node_set.find_all do |node|
      node.to_s.downcase == str_to_match.to_s.downcase
    end
  end

 end
```

Testing with this page, however, returns these results:

```
agent = Mechanize.new
page = agent.get('http://www.angelettiauto.it/parcoveicoli.php').parser
page.xpath("//*[case_insensitive_equals(text(),'Audi')]", XpathFunctions.new).count
# => 1
```

The expected results would have been `4`, because there are 4 Audis listed on the page and I need all of them.

This is of cause caused by using an exact match and not `contains()`, but I can't figure out where to inject it.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by modifying the case_insensitive_equals method like so:

```
def case_insensitive_equals node_set, str_to_match
  node_set.find_all do |node|
    node.to_s.downcase.include?(str_to_match.downcase)
  end
end
```